# Generar un archivo de Excel desde c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una información en un datagrid que cargo directamente desde la base de datos SQL, necesito generar un archivo de excel con la información previamente cargada incluyendo los encabezados.

De qué manera podría hacerlo?.

Comment: Hay un ejemplo en : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Export-DataGridView-62f1f8ff para tu caso mediante Interop

Comment: Tengo el mismo detalle en mi codigo pero en el apartado "excel. en el codigo me marca error. me dice que falta algun import. Importaste una dll o algo desde el Manage Nuget Package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de como utilizarlo.

A ver si te sirve.

```
protected void ibExcele_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {                        
            // Crear un objeto SqlConnection, y luego pasar la ConnectionString al constructor.            
            SqlConnection Conection = new SqlConnection(CadenaString);

            // Utilizar una variable para almacenar la instrucción SQL.
            string SelectString = "SELECT id_pregunta, descripcion, opcion, valor_respuesta, COUNT(id_estudiante) AS Numero_Votos FROM respuestas_encuentas, preguntas WHERE respuestas_encuentas.id_pregunta = preguntas.id GROUP BY id_pregunta, opcion, descripcion, valor_respuesta";                        

            SqlDataAdapter Adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectString, Conection);

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();

            // Abrir la conexión.
            Conection.Open();
            Adaptador.Fill(DS);
            Conection.Close();

            // Creamos un objeto Excel.
            Excel.Application Mi_Excel = default(Excel.Application);
            // Creamos un objeto WorkBook. Para crear el documento Excel.           
            Excel.Workbook LibroExcel = default(Excel.Workbook);
            // Creamos un objeto WorkSheet. Para crear la hoja del documento.
            Excel.Worksheet HojaExcel = default(Excel.Worksheet);            

            // Iniciamos una instancia a Excel, y Hacemos visibles para ver como se va creando el reporte, 
            // podemos hacerlo visible al final si se desea.
            Mi_Excel = new Excel.Application();
            Mi_Excel.Visible = true;

            /* Ahora creamos un nuevo documento y seleccionamos la primera hoja del 
             * documento en la cual crearemos nuestro informe. 
             */
            // Creamos una instancia del Workbooks de excel.            
            LibroExcel = Mi_Excel.Workbooks.Add();
            // Creamos una instancia de la primera hoja de trabajo de excel            
            HojaExcel = LibroExcel.Worksheets[1];
            HojaExcel.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;

            // Hacemos esta hoja la visible en pantalla 
            // (como seleccionamos la primera esto no es necesario
            // si seleccionamos una diferente a la primera si lo
            // necesitariamos).
            HojaExcel.Activate();

            // Crear el encabezado de nuestro informe.
            // La primera línea une las celdas y las convierte un en una sola.            
            HojaExcel.Range["A1:E1"].Merge();
            // La segunda línea Asigna el nombre del encabezado.
            HojaExcel.Range["A1:E1"].Value = "----------------------------------------------";
            // La tercera línea asigna negrita al titulo.
            HojaExcel.Range["A1:E1"].Font.Bold = true;
            // La cuarta línea signa un Size a titulo de 15.
            HojaExcel.Range["A1:E1"].Font.Size = 15;            

            // Crear el subencabezado de nuestro informe
            HojaExcel.Range["A2:E2"].Merge();
            HojaExcel.Range["A2:E2"].Value = "ENCUESTA DE SATISFACCIÓN AL CLIENTE EXTERNO";
            HojaExcel.Range["A2:E2"].Font.Italic = true;
            HojaExcel.Range["A2:E2"].Font.Size = 13;            

            Excel.Range objCelda = HojaExcel.Range["A3", Type.Missing];
            objCelda.Value = "ID";

            objCelda = HojaExcel.Range["B3", Type.Missing];
            objCelda.Value = "Preguntas";

            objCelda = HojaExcel.Range["C3", Type.Missing];
            objCelda.Value = "Opciones";

            objCelda = HojaExcel.Range["D3", Type.Missing];
            objCelda.Value = "Valor de la Respuesta";

            objCelda = HojaExcel.Range["E3", Type.Missing];
            objCelda.Value = "Numero Votos";

            objCelda.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "###,###,###.00";

            int i = 4;
            foreach (DataRow Row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                // Asignar los valores de los registros a las celdas
                HojaExcel.Cells[i, "A"] = Row.ItemArray[0];
                // ID
                HojaExcel.Cells[i, "B"] = Row.ItemArray[1];
                // Pregunta
                HojaExcel.Cells[i, "C"] = Row.ItemArray[2];
                // Opciones
                HojaExcel.Cells[i, "D"] = Row.ItemArray[3];
                // Valor de la Respuesta
                HojaExcel.Cells[i, "E"] = Row.ItemArray[4];
                // Numero Votos

                // Avanzamos una fila
                i++;
            }

            // Seleccionar todo el bloque desde A1 hasta D #de filas.
            Excel.Range Rango = HojaExcel.Range["A3:E" + (i - 1).ToString()];

            // Selecionado todo el rango especificado
            Rango.Select();

            // Ajustamos el ancho de las columnas al ancho máximo del
            // contenido de sus celdas
            Rango.Columns.AutoFit();

            // Asignar filtro por columna
            Rango.AutoFilter(1);            

            // Crear un total general
            //LibroExcel.PrintPreview();
        }
```

Comment: cuál archivo Referencia debería agregar al proyecto para poder usar "Excel.Application", "Excel.Worksheet" ??

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso éste método, pero para que funcione debes agregar, a tu proyecto, referencia al COM de Excel (en mi caso es Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, porque tengo Office 2013)

```
void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog { Filter = @"Excel (*.xls)|*.xls" })
        {
            if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Workbook librosTrabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                Worksheet hojaTrabajo = (Worksheet)librosTrabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                int iCol = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                    if (column.Visible)
                        hojaTrabajo.Cells[1, ++iCol] = column.HeaderText;
                for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        hojaTrabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
                librosTrabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                                      System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, false,
                                      XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false,
                                      System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
                aplicacion.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ojalá te sirva de algo.

Edit: como parámetro le debes pasar el datagridview que quieres exportar.