# Exportar Datos de Gridview a Excel en C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Estoy realizando una funcionalidad con la cual pretendo exportar registros de una gridview a excel

Para esto he creado un archivo local, en la cual pretendo insertar los registros

Aca mi metodo

```
 protected void Exportarexcel(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            String filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"Archivos\SeguimientoCartera\ExportSeguimiento.xlsx");
            String newfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, @"Archivos\SeguimientoCartera\ExportSeguimiento_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx");
            File.Copy(filePath, newfilePath, false);

            Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(newfilePath);
            _Worksheet workSheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets["Hoja1"];


                int filas = GridView1.Rows.Count;


                for (int j = 0; j < filas; j++)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(workSheet.Rows[j].ToString());
                }


                excelWorkbook.Save();
                excelWorkbook.Close();



                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(newfilePath);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                    Response.WriteFile(newfilePath);
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("El archivo no existe.");
                }
        }
```

lo que intento hacer es llenar el `filePath` con los datos que tengo en la `GridView1`

lo que he intentado hacer es escribir el archivo de esta forma `Response.Write(GridView1)`

pero no me ha sido posible. Que puedo hacer para lograrlo

Comment: Revisa si [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59607/generar-un-archivo-de-excel-desde-c/59637#59637) te funciona.

Comment: Hola @AntonioVenerosoContreras estoy desarrollando una app web

Answer (score 1):

Si cuentas con un `GridView` no necesitas iterar las Rows del grid o usas ninguna libreria de office para generar la exportacion, puede directamente trabjar con el render del control y enviarlo al usuario aplicando en `contentype` correcto.

[Export GridView to doc/access/csv/Excel/pdf/xml/html/text/print](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Export-GridView-to-07c9f836)

La exportacion se realiza con estas lineas

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm(); 

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 

GridView1.AllowPaging = false; 

form.Attributes["runat"] = "server"; 
form.Controls.Add(GridView1); 

form.RenderControl(hw);
```

como observaras es el render del grid, previa definicion de un `form` en memoria para poder aplicar el render

Mientras que enviarlo al cliente requiere que primero definas

```
 Response.Clear(); 
 Response.Buffer = true; 
 Response.Charset = ""; 
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Student.xls")); 
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```

Para poder asignar el render en la respuesta

```
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString()); 
Response.Flush(); 
Response.End();
```

Esto deberia enviar al usuario el archivo mostandole el dialogo de descarga

Si necesitas que exporte a `xslx` deberias cambiar el `ContentType`

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=NombreExcelFile.xlsx");
```

Aqui

[Export Data to Excel (.xls, .xlsx) in ASP.NET – C#](https://techbrij.com/export-excel-xls-xlsx-asp-net-npoi-epplus)

se mencionan otras alternativas usando libreria como ser `EPPlus` o `NPOI` estas son recomendadad ya que se basan en `Open Xml` con lo cual no necesitas de Office instalado en la PC

Comment: esta forma en efecto funciona y ya la he probado. He presentado un inconveniente con esta forma y la extensión .xls, ya que al descargar e intentar abrir el archivo muestra una alerta de extensión no compatible. Creeria que es por la version del office que manejo. Lo que requería hacer era tomar el archivo creado local y llenarlo con el contenido de la gridview, posterior a esto si exportarlo o lo otro es como podria indicarle que sea extension .xlsx

Comment: conozco el alerta que mencionas y solo es eso un alerta, edite la repsuesta y agregue el ContentType que deberias usar para este formato

Comment: He utilizado el tipo que me indicas y al exportar el archivo con extension .xlsx me genera una advertencia; Excel no puede abrir el archivo 'ExportSeguimiento_201900205552.xlsx' porque el formato o la extension de este no son validos. Compruebe que el archivo no se ha dañado y que la extension del mismo coincide con el formato del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy intentando utilizar el codigo que comentais pero me da error al ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
Protected Sub bt_ExportarExcel2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_ExportarExcel2.Click
        Try
            Response.Clear()
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.Charset = ""
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Grid1Excel.xls")
            Response.ContentType = "aplication/ms-excel"

            Dim form As New HtmlForm()

            Dim sw As New StringWriter
            Dim html As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

            Grid1.AllowPaging = False
            'Grid1.DataBind()
            form.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            form.Controls.Add(Grid1)
            form.RenderControl(html)


            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
            Grid1.AllowPaging = True

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Esta es la linea que da el error: form.RenderControl(html)

EX.Message  "No se puede procesar el elemento HtmlForm sin una referencia a la instancia de página. Asegúrese de que ha agregado el formulario al árbol de control."    String